# Google Play says to sign into Google account (In-app billing)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-account

I've been trying to solve this problem for a week and I've no any success. The thing is that, I handle if the user of the app tries to buy subscription without being signed into Google account and I lead him to Google sign in screen, but even after user has signed in and tries to buy subscription Google play says he needs to sign into Google account. On this very step I've been debugging and AccountManager's getAccounts() returns array including account that has been recently added by the user. And only after I kill the app and launch it again, Google play sees user's Google account and purchase works fine. Any ideas how to fix this problem? 
Here is the method which is called when the user clicks "Purchase" button:

```
accountsArray = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
   if(accountsArray != null && accountsArray.length >= 1){
       SystemUtils.getCache(this, new CacheUtils.CallBack<Cache>() {
           @Override
           public void run(Cache cache) {
               billingActivityCache = cache;
           }
       });

       JSONObject payload = null;
       try {
           payload = new JSONObject()
                   .put("user", new JSONObject()
                           .put("id", billingActivityCache.getUser().getId()
                           ));
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       Bundle buyIntentBundle = null;
       try {
           buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),
                   currentSku, "subs", payload.toString());
       } catch (RemoteException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
       try {
           startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                   BUY_KEY, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                   Integer.valueOf(0));
       } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   } else{
       Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);
       intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[]{"com.google"});
       startActivityForResult(intent, LOGIN_GOOGLE);
   }
```

Comment: show the code for that

Comment: can you please show some code for this @Nataliya

Comment: so its work for second time but not instantly..right

Comment: @PratikDasa yeah, it works, but only after I relaunch the app

Comment: Then your code is not completely bad...its working but I think you have do your main task when you loggedin via google do subscription at that time and refresh it. As per me when you siging via google signedin is not completed and you doing tasks that may happen @NataliyaBorodina

Comment: have you got the solution or not?? @NataliyaBorodina

Comment: @NataliyaBorodina are you working for ekreative in which country?

Answer (score 0):

(Not a part of answer but)
First, do NOT put personal info in plane text as a bundle.
User id is a personal info.
Check Google privacy policy.

---

Related Q&A here.
[Change Gmail account to make in-app purchase?]
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70215/change-gmail-account-to-make-in-app-purchase